# how to prevent switch to opener tab on js window.opener reload in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, reload

When reloading opener window in JavaScript this way:

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
```

The opener tab gets focused in Firefox and this is undesirable.
I don't get this behavior in Chrome.
It may be due to a Firefox update because this is an old system and this problem is not reported previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1694927 which is fixed in Firefox 87.